# How can I read a datetime from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I convert a string to date and save the CSV:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.to_csv('dates.csv')
```

But when I try to read the CSV, it get the column as str:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dates.csv')
type(df['date'].iloc[0])
<type 'str'>
```

How can I save it as a datetime and read as a datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `parse_dates` parameter in `read_csv`.

> parse_dates : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict
>       If True -> try parsing the index.
>       If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
>       If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column.
>       {'foo' : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result 'foo'
>       A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

So:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['date_col_1', 'date_col2', etc...])
```

A specific example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-1-1', '2015-2-1', '2015-3-1']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.to_csv('dates.csv')

df2 = pd.read_csv('dates.csv')

>>> type(df2['date'].iloc[0])
str

df2 = pd.read_csv('dates.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

>>> type(df2['date'].iloc[0])
pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```